# Dúvida sobre getter em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Vi estudando sobre **computed properties** do Vues.js que estas propriedades computadas utilizam de **`getters`** e **`setters`** também, e estudando sobre o **get** caí neste código de exemplo no site da [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
var expr = "foo";

var obj = {
   get [expr]() { 
      return "bar";
   }
};

console.log(obj.foo);      // bar
```

> **Aí me surgiu a dúvida:**

- Get só é utilizado para se trabalhar com o valor da variável enquanto mantém o valor original da mesma ou teria mais alguma aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> só é utilizado para se trabalhar com o valor da variável enquanto mantém o valor original da mesma ou teria mais alguma aplicação?

Não, um getter pode retornar algo apenas baseado no estado de variáveis ou propriedades (privadas ou não), não somente o valor de uma delas. É bem na linha das computed properties do Vue que você citou, tem várias utilidades. Como os getters são funções, eles podem retornar basicamente qualquer coisa.

Por exemplo, um getter que faz uma conta e retorna o resultado:

```js
var divisao = {
   dividendo: 10,
   divisor:   5,
   get resultado() { 
      return this.dividendo/this.divisor;
   }
};
console.log(divisao.resultado); // 2
divisao.dividendo = 50;
console.log(divisao.resultado); // 10
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta man. Não teria um exemplo para nos dar? Pois o que achei foi apenas este exemplo do site da Mozilla e me deixou com mais dúvidas do que certezas. :(

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo

Comment: Muito bom man, entendido perfeitamente!